# place tld file META-INF folder in the jar in m2e project

Tags: tags, m2eclipse, tld, meta-inf

I have to place a custom tld file in the META-INF folder in the jar for a project developed using m2eclipse plugin. Can anyone help me?

Comment: This got resolved when I created META-INF folder under /src/main/resources and placed tld file in it.

Comment: I thought such files had to be put under src/main/webapp/META-INF/ but it actually didn't work; I moved them under src/main/resources/META-INF/ as you suggest and it works perfectly. Thanks a lot !